# Set UILabel & UITextField language to be different then App language

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I have an app that has the Base language set to Arabic

[image]

So by default, the language for every `UILabel` & `UITextField` is going to be arabic.
[image]

The text of the `UITextFields` or `UILabels` is either from an API or the user enters them.

When setting the `text` property for the `UILabel` to a number

```
phoneNumberLabelOutlet.text = "123"
```

the system automatically localizes them to Arabic. However, I would like the numbers to be always in Latin numbers (English).

For example, in the following `UITextField` I entered "Hello World 123".
The app didn't localize Hello World ( obviously) but it did localize the digits.[image]

Any idea how can i do that ?

Comment: Use variadic parameters

Comment: Variadic parameters that allow arbitrary number of parameters to be passed to a function ? I don't see how they apply here. Please let me know If I'm missing out on something

Comment: Sorry meant String interpolation i.e - let multiplier = 3
let message = "\(multiplier) times 2.5 is \(Double(multiplier) * 2.5)" so you put variables in between your field that are not translated